# Add the individual columns and rows in a 2D Array and display in a 1D Array table?

Tags: java, arrays, random, methods

I'm a beginner in Java programming. I have created the 2D array that generates random numbers to fill the array.

But now I need to calculate the sum of the rows and columns individually and store the values in a separate table formatted in a 1D array using a method...

This is what I have so far:

```js
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;

    public class Q42 {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  //create the grid
  final int rowWidth = 4;
  final int colHeight = 5;

  Random rand = new Random();

  int [][] board = new int [rowWidth][colHeight];

  //fill the grid
  for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
   for (int col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++) {
    board[row][col] = rand.nextInt(10);
   }
  }

  //display output
  for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
   for(int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
    System.out.print(board[i][j] + " ");
    //System.out.println();
   }
   System.out.println();
  
} //end of main

 public static int[] sumTableRows(int[][] table)
 {
     int rows = table.length;
     int cols = table[0].length;

     int[] sum = new int[rows];
     for(int x=0; x<rows; x++)
         for(int y=0; y<cols; y++)
             sum[x] += table[x][y];
     return sum;     
 }

    } //end of class Main
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem? At a glance, it seems you're doing fine.

Comment: @JohnSensebe I have no idea how to store the values in a separate table formatted in a 1D array using a method.

Comment: what do you mean by `separate table formatted in a 1D ` ?

Comment: What do you think `sumTableRows` does?

Comment: @789 I have to record the sums of the individual rows and columns in a table format. I just assumed it would be the best to format that table in a 1D array in a method. How would I do that?

Comment: @JohnSensebe But how to I call the method so that the data displays in a table format?

Comment: An array *is* a table. You look something up using one value (the index) and get another value back.

Comment: Tell me if i understand you correctly: you have a table of random numbers. you want to sum every column/row and save it in a variable? then you need 1D array

Comment: @789 I understand that. It's just that I don't understand how to do that. Could you help me out please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if i understand you correctly, this is what you want to do:
You have a 2D array with random values. you want to sum up all the values in every row and put in a variable. Easy. This is how you do it:

```
public static int[] sumTableRows(int[][] table)
{
    int rows = table.length;
    int cols = table[0].length;

    int[] sum = new int[rows];//make an array for sums

    for(int i=0; i<rows; i++) {

        for(int j=0; j<cols; j++){//iterate over all vars in the table array
            int temp  = table[i][j];//take value in point (i,j)
            sum[i] += temp;//sum it in sum[i].
        }
    }
    return sum;   //return the 1D array  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!